# How to automatically use rjsx-mode instead of js-jsx-mode

Tags: js-mode, jsx, rjsx-mode

When I work with JSX files Emacs automatically switches to `js-jsx-mode` and acts sluggishly. When I switch it to `rjsx-mode` it works much faster. So the idea is to override one mode with another, so that rjsx-mode is used instead of js-jsx-mode.

What is the best way to achieve this effect?

Comment: See the variable `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: @NickD thanks but this not quite solve an issue. `auto-mode-alist` binds certain file extensions to certain major modes but in case of JS, JSX and JS files often use the same ".js" extension. I look for smarter solution, that will not only figure out the file is JS file but JSX in particular, as `js-jsx-mode` does in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Emacs 27.1, this will depend on whether or not you want <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `js-jsx-detect-syntax` to be taken into account.

When that option is enabled, the default `js-mode` will inspect the syntax of Javascript files with a plain `.js` filename extension and decide whether or not to enable JSX support.

When that option is NOT enabled (or if you are using Emacs 26), the decision is purely based on whether or not the filename has a `.jsx` extension.

If your JSX files will *always* have the `.jsx` extension, then you could do this:

```el
;; Use `rjsx-mode' for .jsx files.
;; `auto-mode-alist' is already taken care of if you've
;; installed `rjsx-mode' as a package.
;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . rjsx-mode))
;; Never check for JSX syntax in regular .js files.
(setq js-jsx-detect-syntax nil)
```

If there's a chance that the syntax checking is needed, then integrating the two turns out to be a little fiddly, on account of `js-mode` still being an ancestor of `rjsx-mode`.  Try the following config:

```el
;; Use `rjsx-mode' for JSX files.
;; `auto-mode-alist' is already taken care of if you've
;; installed `rjsx-mode' as a package.
;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . rjsx-mode))
(advice-add 'js-jsx-enable :override #'my-js-jsx-enable)
(defun my-js-jsx-enable ()
  "Use `rjsx-mode' instead of `js-jsx-mode'."
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'js-jsx--detect-and-enable) (lambda () t)))
    (rjsx-mode)))
;; Prevent the `rjsx-mode' ancestor `js-mode' from continuing to check
;; for JSX code.
(add-hook 'rjsx-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (remove-hook 'after-change-functions
                                         #'js-jsx--detect-after-change t)))
```

You might check the issue queue for `rjsx-mode`, and open a new issue if necessary, so that this sort of thing could be addressed by default.

Note that in Emacs 27.1 the actual minor mode `js-jsx-mode` is just one of multiple possible ways for `js-jsx-enable` to be called, and consequently there's no benefit to targeting this mode specifically.  This *was* different in earlier versions of Emacs, however it looks as if (a) `js-jsx-mode` didn't do very much before Emacs 27.1, and (b) it was only triggered for `.jsx` filenames (which we've already accounted for); so regardless of which Emacs version you're using, I don't believe there's any benefit to messing with `js-jsx-mode` itself.

Comment: `(advice-add 'js-jsx-mode :override #'rjsx-mode)` looks very interesting, I will test it in battle. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it but I get an error `File mode specification error: (error Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’)` when opening js file. So it end up in `fundamental mode`.

Comment: I've now looked at `rsjx-mode` and I see that it derives from `js-mode`, meaning that my initial suggestion introduced some infinite recursion.  Try it now.  I've changed the approach to supporting the syntax checking feature in 27.1, and also fixed a dumb typo (extra parens) in the `auto-mode-alist` code (but also commented that line out, because `rsjx-mode.el` already updates `auto-mode-alist`, so you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks @phils , meanwhile I switched entirely to rjsx for every JS matters - it seams faster. Will see how it handle everything, and in case of problems I will try your solution.

Comment: You could also consider using `js2-mode` for regular JS (you already have it -- `rjsx-mode` builds on top of it).  I've no idea whether there are advantages to doing that, or if in practice it's fine to use `rjsx-mode` for everything.  (My answer is very specific to the standard `js-mode` implementation though.)

Comment: Yes, `rjsx-mode` handle all JS pretty well so far, definitely faster than `js-mode`. I will check your solution on spare time and approve an answer if everything works well.